# Rails elasticsearh reindex document when has_many model is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-rails gems

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model', '~> 0.1.6'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.1.6'
```

My modles:

**place.rb**

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
   include PlaceElasticSearch
   ...
   has_many :order_rooms
   ...
end
```

**orer_room.rb**

```
class OrderRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
end
```

**place_elastic_search.rb**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

module PlaceElasticSearch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    index_name "places-#{Rails.env}"

    settings INDEX_SETTINGS do
      mappings dynamic: 'false' do
        ...
        indexes :order_rooms, type: 'nested', include_in_root: true do
          indexes :max_persons,          type: 'integer'
        end
      end
    end

    after_touch() { __elasticsearch__.index_document }

  end
end
```

I need reindex place elasticsearch document after create/delete/update order_room.

I added after_save callback for order_room model

**order_room.rb**

```
after_save :update_place_document

def update_place_document
  place.__elasticsearch__.index_document if Place.respond_to?('__elasticsearch__')
end
```

But it doesnt work if i have updated or deleted old order room.

Any ideas?  Where i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, looks like place has cached order room object. If i add reload to `after_save` method or `place(cache: false)` all works. Also need to add `after_destroy` callback

**order_room.rb**

```
after_save :update_place_document
after_destroy :update_place_document

def update_place_document
  place(cache: false).__elasticsearch__.index_document if Place.respond_to?('__elasticsearch__')
end
```

Comment: Using `place(cache: false)` worked for us, which is amazing. But we don't know why it works. Do you have any documentation for passing that argument?